# How to insert http:// to a website address whitch is inserted automatically with php

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I have the following code:

```
                // Which group by default?
                $group_name = ($coppa) ? 'REGISTERED_COPPA' : 'REGISTERED';

                $sql = 'SELECT group_id
                        FROM ' . GROUPS_TABLE . "
                        WHERE group_name = '" . $db->sql_escape($group_name) . "'
                                AND group_type = " . GROUP_SPECIAL;
                $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
                $row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);
                $db->sql_freeresult($result);

                if (!$row)
                {
                    trigger_error('NO_GROUP');
                }

                $group_id = $row['group_id'];


                    $user_type = USER_NORMAL;
                    $user_actkey = '';
                    $user_inactive_reason = 0;
                    $user_inactive_time = 0;

                $bday = explode('/', $fb_user->birthday);
                $user_row = array(
                    'username'              => $data['username'],
                    'user_password'         => phpbb_hash($data['new_password']),
                    'user_email'            => $data['email'],
                    'group_id'              => (int) $group_id,
                    'user_timezone'         => (float) $data['tz'],
                    'user_dst'              => $is_dst,
                    'user_lang'             => $data['lang'],
                    'user_type'             => $user_type,
                    'user_actkey'           => $user_actkey,
                    'user_ip'               => $user->ip,
                    'user_regdate'          => time(),
                    'user_inactive_reason'  => $user_inactive_reason,
                    'user_inactive_time'    => $user_inactive_time,
                    'al_fb_id'              => $fb_user->id,
                    'user_avatar_type'      => AVATAR_REMOTE,
                    'user_avatar_width'     => 100,
                    'user_avatar_height'    => 100,
                    'user_avatar'           => 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fb_user->id . '/picture?type=normal',
                    'al_fb_avatar_sync'     => 1,
                    'al_fb_profile_sync'    => 1,

                    'user_website'                    => (!$fb_user->website) ? '' : $fb_user->website,
                    'user_from'                   => (!$fb_user->location->name) ? '' : $fb_user->location->name,
                    'user_occ'                 => (!$fb_user->work[0]->employer->name) ? '' : $fb_user->work[0]->employe->name,

                    'user_birthday'              => sprintf('%2d-%2d-%4d', $bday[1], $bday[0], $bday[2]),
                );
```

And I think that this line:
'user_website'                    => (!$fb_user->website) ? '' : $fb_user->website, 
is responsable for inserting the website address from facebook to the user profile on my website when they choose to login with a facecbook account. The website address is inserted as it is, with without http:// in front but I need it to be inserted with "http://" . I use a phpbb forum and the mod for login with facebook is: https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=70&t=1883675 
the code responsible for this, can be found in the files from the mod:
al_fb_connect.php
includes/ucp/ucp_alternatelogin.php
Can somebody help me with this one please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help you:

```
'user_website' => (!$fb_user->website) ? '' : 'http://' . $fb_user->website,
```

just placed a http:// between the double quotes.

Comment: I found another line that may contain website adress, can this be the one ?: $data['user_website']                    = isset($fb_user->website) ? $fb_user->website : '';

Comment: Try to set value with http://
` $website = 'http://' . $fb_user->website`
after $user_row and later 
`'user_website'=> $website´

Comment: Here is the entire php code for /alternatelogin/al_fb_connect.php : http://pastebin.com/hRC1xBhH and this one is for /includes/ucp/ucp_alternatelogin.php : http://pastebin.com/JvRVmutn

Comment: I`m sorry but I don`t know PHP and don`t understand what to change and where. Can you be more specific please ? Thank you.

Comment: First create a var called "$website". Assign the value to this var "$website = 'http://' . $fb_user->website". And replace $fb_user->website inside "$user_row = array(..." with $website